# App deployed with mup, how to access using domain name?

Tags: meteor

Just deployed an app via mup, and it is accessible directly using the IP address in the browser. How can I get my domain name working with the app?

Answer (score 1):

In your mup configuration file (`mup.json`), make sure you indicate the proper `ROOT_URL` under the `env` sub-document :

```
"env": {
  [...]
  "ROOT_URL": "http://domain.com"
  [...]
},
```

Then within your registrar admin panel, create an `A` record and set the value to the webserver IP address. You can also create a `CNAME` record to make `www.domain.com` an alias of `domain.com` if you want to handle `www` redirect properly.